# Assert multiple related variables as non-null and not undefined based on a boolean flag

Tags: typescript, option-type

My TS code is compiled using `strictNullChecks` and `noImplicitAny`, and I have a lot of optionals to deal with. I want to use a boolean checker function to indicate whether the variable (and other related variables) should be defined or not. Simplified example:

```
class Person {
    private firstName: string;
    private firstNameSyllables: number;

    private middleName?: string;
    private middleNameSyllables?: number;
    private hasMiddleName: boolean;

    constructor(firstName: string, middleName?: string){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.firstNameSyllables = calculateSyllables(firstName);

        if(typeof middleName !== "undefined"){
            this.middleName = middleName;
            this.middleNameSyllables = calculateSyllables(middleName);
            this.hasMiddleName = true;
        } else {
            this.hasMiddleName = false;
        }
    }

    // Stub function
    calculateSyllables(name: string): number { return name.length / 3; }
    hasMiddleNameCheck(): boolean { return this.hasMiddleName; }

    getStartOfNameWithSyllables(): string {
        if(this.hasMiddleNameCheck()){
            // ERROR: middleName and middleNameSyllables may be undefined
            return `${this.firstName}: ${this.firstNameSyllables},` +
                   `${this.middleName}: ${this.middleNameSyllables}`;
        } else {
            return `${this.firstName}: ${this.firstNameSyllables}`;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the compiler to infer that both `middleName` and `middleNameSyllables` should be defined, as a result of `this.hasMiddleNameCheck()` returning `true`? Currently I have to work around the problem by using type assertions such as `middleName as string` or `middleName!`, but this is undesirable during refactors that make variables optional, as it involves tracking down every single use of a possibly undefined variable.

Comment: What about `null` value? Why do you want to use a boolean flag if you could check the field itself for having a value or not? There are limits to the compiler - it's not magic.

Comment: Why not just ditch the flag and explicitly check `if (this.middleName!=null && this.middleNameSyllables!=null)` which then clearly matches the content of the following statements? The `x!=null` is true for both `x===null` and `x===undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [special type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5906) of [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) if you allow changing some of your `private` members to `protected`:

```
class Person {
    ...
    protected middleName?: string;
    protected middleNameSyllables?: number;
    protected hasMiddleName: boolean;
    ...
}
```

and after the `Person` declaration you can declare a new subclass called `PersonWithMiddleName` (which you are never going to actually instantiate):

```
class PersonWithMiddleName extends Person {
  hasMiddleName: true;
  middleName: string;
  middleNameSyllables: number;
}
```

Finally, change the return type of `hasMiddleNameCheck()`:

```
hasMiddleNameCheck(): this is PersonWithMiddleName  {
  return this.hasMiddleName;
}
```

And everything should work for you.  The `private`/`protected` nature of the members you're trying to guard makes this more complicated; if they were public you wouldn't need to subclass `Person`.

---

If this feels too convoluted to you, you may want to make the related variables a single object like

```
interface MiddleName {
  name: string;
  syllables: number;
}
```

and then have `Person` have an optional `MiddleName`:

```
class Person {
    ...
    private middleName?: MiddleName;
    ...
}
```

Then you just have to check if `this.middleName` is defined, and access `this.middleName.name` and `this.middleName.syllables`, which is not much more verbose and makes it very obvious that these are either all defined or all undefined.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: The first one is a beautiful solution; just what I was looking for, thanks! The second solution works for simple cases, but not when an optional property might be found defined in two different situations (ie. one would not simply be able to nest the optional property under one class like `MiddleName`).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix of all would be to not have `this.middleNameSyllables` as optional, but instead default it to `0`. Combine that with an explicit check for `this.middleName != null` instead of the flag variable and the compiler will be happy with both values:

```
private middleNameSyllables: number = 0;
...
getStartOfNameWithSyllables(): string {
    if(this.middleName != null){
        return `${this.firstName}: ${this.firstNameSyllables},` +
               `${this.middleName}: ${this.middleNameSyllables}`;
    } else {
        return `${this.firstName}: ${this.firstNameSyllables}`;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer to keep the number optional as well, just check both values in the condition and again the type inferencing will know that neither is `undefined` when you use it:

```
getStartOfNameWithSyllables(): string {
    if(this.middleName != null && this.middleNameSyllables != null){
        return `${this.firstName}: ${this.firstNameSyllables},` +
               `${this.middleName}: ${this.middleNameSyllables}`;
    } else {
        return `${this.firstName}: ${this.firstNameSyllables}`;
    }
}
```